# iptables NEW connections vs. --syn

Tags: linux, iptables

What's the difference between:

```
iptables ... -m state --state NEW
```

and

```
iptables ... --syn
```

The first one should select NEW connections, but AFAIK new connections are made by sending a TCP syn flag.
The other one means just that - packets with a syn flag.

Can you give any practical examples when the above commands return different results?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `--syn` flag is useful to check TCP traffic, but the `NEW` state can be used for other protocols (including `TCP`) like `UDP` and `ICMP`. I can say that `NEW` is more general than `--syn` TCP option.

From the iptables manual, you can read:

```
NEW    meaning that the packet has started a new connection,
       or otherwise associated with a connection which has not seen packets in both directions
```

An example, a DNS request will match the `NEW` state, but it will not match a rule with `--syn` option. Simply, it is a UDP datagram.

Also, the `--syn` option can be used to check for TCP packets with bad flags combination to drop them.

Also, you can use both of these options together to check for `NEW` TCP flows without `--syn` as first packet and drop them such as:

```
$ sudo iptables -A bad_tcp_packets -p tcp ! --syn -m state --state NEW -j LOG --log-prefix "New not syn:"
```

Here, we are adding this types of packets to a user-defined chain called `bad_tcp_packets` to be dropped/logged, etc...

Comment: Would the "opposite" be a bad TCP packet as well? `... -p tcp --syn -m state ! --state NEW ...`, or can that happen on a quick reconnect?

Answer (score 0):

One extra point. `--syn` can be used in `raw` table, but `--new` cannot (because in raw table it's way too early to categorize packets).